# How to share reviews using  yelp in android

Tags: android, api, yelp

In one of my android app, I need to integrate yelp in the app. Actually , I need to post users reviews to yelp and check users Reviews using **Yelp Business API** .

Please give me some hints or examples that how  can we post reviews using yelp's API and check those reviews using my app.

As much as I know we can do this using the **API2.0v- Business API of yelp** (reference URL http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business ) but I could not find any way  to post the review from the app . They have just given an API url (sample request: http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/yelp-san-francisco ) which provide a response (in json format) that includes the reveiws of that city but what how can a user post a review using this API.

Any idea or help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yelp API does not support the ability to submit reviews for a business.